# Laravel BelongsToMany with two pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following table structure:

#### products

- id

#### product_formats

- id
- product_id

#### product_prices

- id
- product_format_id
- market_id

#### markets

- id

A product can have multiple formats, with each having their own price which belongs in a different market. How can I retrieve the list of Markets from the Product model?

I used to have a single pivot table, however now I have two pivot.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function markets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Market::class);
    }
}
```

### Update

To get the result I want, I did the following:

```
public function markets()
{
    return Market::whereIn('id', $this->prices()->distinct()->pluck('market_id')->toArray());
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish this via a relationship.

Comment: Simple. Just do a `one to many` relation between  `products` and `product_formats` and a `many to many` relation between `product_formats` and `markets`

Comment: Then if you want to retrieve the list of Markets from one product just do `$product->product_format[0]->markets`. I said `format[0]` because of the one to many relation

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Wouldn't that retrieve the markets of my first format only? I want all the unique markets of each formats.

Comment: It depends in how you query your data. if you want all the unique markets of a single product you can do something like `markets->whereHas("product_formats.products", function($query){$query->where("id", myProductId);})->get()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to build relationships in models.

**ProductModel:**

```
public function productFormats()
{
  return $this->belongTo(ProductFormatsModel::class);
}
```

**ProductFormatsModel:**

```
public function productPrices()
{
  return $this->belongTo(ProductPricesModel::class);
}
```

**ProductPricesModel:**

```
public function markets()
{
  return $this->hasOne(MarketsModel::class);
}
```

**in Controller:**

```
foreach($product->productFormats as $productFormat) 
{
  foreach($productFormat->productPrices as $productPrice)
  {
     var_dump($productPrice->markets);
  }
}
```

---

### For unique markets

**in ProductModel:**

```
public function productPrices()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
                      'App\ProductPricesModel', 
                      'App\ProductFormatsModel',
                      'product_id', 
                      'product_format_id'
                      'id',
                      'id'
                     );
    }
```

**in Controller**

```
foreach($product->productPrices as $productPrice)
{
  var_dump($productPrice->markets)
}
```

Comment: This will not give me unique markets though. Also I want the markets in one collection.

Comment: @ChinLeung What is meant by unique markets. 2 identical markets can match one product? So for each product markets will be in a separate collection

Comment: This won't do, the markets are in different collections. I want them all in the same collection.

Comment: @ChinLeung So you want the market-> product, not product-> market?

Comment: @ChinLeung just do not understand, all the markets that belong to the product will be in one collection, which markets do you still want to bathe there?

Comment: I want it both way. $market->product to retrieve the list of products in one collection and $product->market to retrieve the list of markets that has the products.

Comment: @ChinLeung Of course, well, the product->market already exists, you can already make a market->product on this example